# How to copy a private attribute when using CGLIB?

Tags: java, spring, cglib

I have the following example where I try to copy a private attribute from the source instance to the target instance.

```
public class MyClass {
  public void cloneTo(MyClass target) {
    target.identifier = this.identifier; // identifier is not null
    System.out.println(target.getIdentifier()) // problem: prints null
  }
}
```

This code usually should work, but the problem is that the `MyClass` instance is a `CGLIB` proxy: `MyClass$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$someId`, and in this case, the identifier attribute is not set in the proxied target class, so when I call `getIdentifier()`, it returns null instead of the identifier.

Is it possible to copy private attributes without creating a getter/setter for each attribute?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

I take it from your question that you created a proxy `MyClass$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$someId` that delegates its method invocations to another instance of `MyClass`?

Field operations in Java are not dispatched dynamically, i.e. there is no way to trigger an action when a field is set or read. This is only possible when a method is invoked. This means that there is no way to set the field of `MyClass` when `MyClass$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$someId` is set.

Instead you need to:

1. Define a setter for writing fields.
2. Make `MyClass$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$someId` not to be a delegator but an actual substitute for `MyClass`.